# C# Load Application Settings from other project?

Tags: c#, load, copy, settings

I have a bunch of property settings saved in an application (WinForms btw, I have never touched WPF) in a project, and I'm re-writing that project again due to messy coding. The problem is, there are around 50 settings (the settings which you can see from Project Properties and the Settings option) in that project and I don't know how to copy them to the new project. Is there a way to do this or will I have to add them all over again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The settings are saved in two settings files (settings.settings and settings.designer.cs)

You can just copy these files to your new project and overwrite the empty ones with the ones from the previous project.

You might need to edit the files *before copying* them to make sure the namespace matches the namespace on the new project.

Comment: Where is settings.designer.cs? I can't find it in the Solution Explorer or in the Settings option either..

Comment: In the solution explorer click on the little triangle to open the Properties folder and you should see files in there. You can also just get the files directly with Windows Explorer they are under the properties folder in your disk.

Comment: Okay so I got it working, because in the view code window I can access those settings using Settings.Default.stuff, however the settings aren't updated in the designer (I mean in the Settings option in the Properties menu). Why is that? <- Nevermind, I forgot to rename the namespace.

Answer (score 3):

In the Solution Explorer open $MyPojectName\Properties\Settings.settings with XML Editor (use Open With... context menu option) and copy them where you want.

And if you want to override another project's settings file be ready to renew
root element's GeneratedClassNamespace attribute.

Comment: THAT is a simple yet working solution. Just open the file and copy/paste whatever portion you need, except the headers, and voila!

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Properties directory of the project with the settings you want.
2. Copy the Settings.Designer.cs and Settings.settings files.
3. Go to the Properties directory of the new project and paste them.
4. Open the Settings.Designer.cs (I use notepad for this) and change the namespace to match your new project.
5. The settings should now be available in your new project. You can view them by clicking on the Settings.settings file in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score -2):

just copy the app.config file to destination project folder